# Hook up of two threads

Tags: java, multithreading, object

I hava got 2 Threads in java and I want hook up them. I used class PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream, but I want sending objects, how I do it?
Thank you

Comment: "I used class PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream" -> Then you can show it here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a `Queue`. The producer cam pump objects on the queue which the consumer can receive and process.

There are several implementations of `BlockingQueue` which you can use in java, for example `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

You have to elaborate if you have any specific use case.